# How to stream music on app using the API Jukebox with swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to stream music to my app using this library I found online called Jukebox. Heres a link to their page: https://github.com/teodorpatras/Jukebox

```
import UIKit
import Jukebox
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var jukebox = Jukebox()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.jukebox = Jukebox(delegate: self, items: [ JukeboxItem(URL: NSURL(string: "http://mixtapemonkey.com/mixtapes/zip/491/Chance%20The%20Rapper%20-%2010Day%20Official%20Final/03%20Nostalgia.mp3")!)
        ])
}
```

I get an error where it says 'Jukebox(delegate: self' stating that I **cannot convert the value of type 'ViewController' to expected argument type 'JukeboxDelegate?'**

```
@IBAction func Play(sender: UIButton) {
    self.jukebox.play()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

where am i going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you've failed to inherit from the Jukebox delegate in your class declaration. Should be something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, JukeboxDelegate {

    var jukebox = Jukebox()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.jukebox = Jukebox(delegate: self, items: [ JukeboxItem(URL: NSURL(string: "http://mixtapemonkey.com/mixtapes/zip/491/Chance%20The%20Rapper%20-%2010Day%20Official%20Final/03%20Nostalgia.mp3")!)
    ])
    }
}
```

Since these delegate methods aren't optional, you'll also have to make your ViewController conform to the delegate by including the delegate methods, listed below.

> Defines the five possible states that Jukebox can be in.

```
public protocol JukeboxDelegate : class {
    func jukeboxStateDidChange(jukebox : Jukebox)
    func jukeboxPlaybackProgressDidChange(jukebox : Jukebox)
    func jukeboxDidLoadItem(jukebox : Jukebox, item : JukeboxItem)
}
```

The library seems to be written in Swift, and unless you put some extra effort into it, delegate methods can't be optional which is why you're getting the error about your VC not conforming to the methods. You at least have to have the method signatures in your class, and it's up to you whether you want anything to happen when they're called.

Comment: Yes, this helped but I now get an error saying "type 'viewcontroller' does not conform to protocol 'JukeboxDelegate'

Comment: I'm a newbie at this, how do I go about doing this? I really appreciate the help

Comment: @Amissi the auto code complete is smart enough to know the methods exist now since you've conformed to the protocol, so if you just start typing the method names they will show up.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know Jukebox - but something doesn't work with your ViewController. Your ViewController is a class not a class instance. You need to first create an instance of this controller.

Maybe something in this direction helps .. but im not good in Swift, too.

```
let VCJukeBox = UIViewController()?

VCJukeBox.jukebox = Jukebox(delegate: self, items: [ JukeboxItem(URL: NSURL(string: "yoururl.mp3")!)
    ])
```

Im not good in swift, too - but maybe this helps somehow.